# httpcontext.getglobalresourceobject in asp .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NV515.png)

// Not able to find other option for "GetGlobalResourceObject" in .net core

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

`HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject` method only can be appled to `.NET Framework` instead of `.NET Core`.

If you want to get the key value in resource file in ASP.NET Core, you can use `IStringLocalizer` like below:

1.Create `SharedResource.cs` in **root** of the application

```
public class SharedResource
{
}
```

2.Controller

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IStringLocalizer<SharedResource> _sharedLocalizer;
    public HomeController(IStringLocalizer<SharedResource> sharedLocalizer)
    {
        _sharedLocalizer = sharedLocalizer;
    }
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var data = _sharedLocalizer["Hello"];   //get the value if key=Hello
        return View();
    }
}
```

3.Startup.cs:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllersWithViews()
            .AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix)
            .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization();
        services.AddLocalization(o => o.ResourcesPath = "Resources");
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        //...
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();
        var supportedCultures = new[]
        {
            new CultureInfo("en"),
            new CultureInfo("fr"),
        };

        app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions
        {
            DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en"),
            // Formatting numbers, dates, etc.
            SupportedCultures = supportedCultures,
            // UI strings that we have localized.
            SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures
        });

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
}
```

Resource file

[image]

Project Structure

[image]

Request URL: `https://localhost:portNum/Home/Index?culture=fr`.

Result:

[image]

More details you can refer to the official document:

[Globalization and localization in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-6.0)